# VBA Script fails when trying to save as .XLSX

Tags: vba, excel, fso

The following script has been written to open all .xlsm file types within a folder and save them as .xlsx types in a new directory but the script keeps failing when trying to save as .xlsx.

The error message returned is a run-time error '1004'

All attempts to remedy this have failed, any help is much appriciated and I thank you in advance.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fils = fso.GetFolder("FILE LOCATION").Files

FldrPicker = "FILE LOCATION"
With FldrPicker
myPath = FldrPicker
End With
myExtension = "*.xlsm"
myfile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

filepath = "NEW FILE LOCATION"

Do While myfile <> ""
Set wb = workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myfile)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.SaveAs = myfile & ".xlsx"
wb.Close Savechanges:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Loop
```

Comment: `wb.SaveAs` can't be assigned a value, you need to pass it a parameter - i.e. `wb.SaveAs myfile & ".xlsx"`  (Note:  If you had opened a file called "abc.xlsm" from the "C:\Temp1\Temp2" directory, you will be creating a file called "abc.xlsm.xlsx" in the active directory, which is probably where the Excel application is stored - so you probably really want 'wb.SaveAs myPath & Left(myfile, Len(myfile) - 5) & ".xlsx"`)

Comment: I have added the following the following parameters yet the same error is being returned.
`teamname = Left(myfile, Len(myfile) - 5) & ".xlsx"` 
`Destination = filepath & teamname`
`wb.SaveAs = Destination`

Comment: If the error is being triggered due to the warning that `Excel` **really** doesn't like you trying to save a `macro enabled` workbook as a plain file, add a `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to the start of your code and a `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` as the end to force the issue.

Comment: Please read @YowE3K answer. You are still assigning a value to `wb.SaveAs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `SaveAs` is a `Method` of the `Workbook` object, it can't be assigned a value, so you can't have a statement of the form:

```
    wb.SaveAs = .....
```

The [MSDN documentation for SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) shows that it can be passed many parameters, either by position or by name:

> *expression* .SaveAs(*FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local*)
>
> *expression* A variable that represents a Workbook object.

One of the valid syntaxes for what you have written is:

```
    wb.SaveAs myfile & ".xlsx"
```

---

However, if you had opened a file called "abc.xlsm" from the "C:\Temp1\Temp2" directory, you will be creating a file called "abc.xlsm.xlsx" in the current directory, which is probably where the Excel application is stored - so you probably really want

```
    wb.SaveAs FileName:=myPath & Left(myfile, Len(myfile) - 5) & ".xlsx"
```

or possibly

```
    wb.SaveAs FileName:=myPath & Left(myfile, Len(myfile) - 5) & ".xlsx", _
              FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

to force the Save to be in a non-macro-enabled format.

---

But the main point to remember is ... *you cannot assign a value to a `Method`*.